# NSImage -drawAtPoint: Draws Too Small

Tags: image, macos, cocoa, merge

I'm using this to combine 2 NSImages :

```
newImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(size1.width,
                                                    size1.height + size2.height)];
[newImage lockFocus];
[firimage drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(0, 0)
             fromRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, size1.width, size1.height)
            operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
             fraction:1.0];
[secimage drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(0, size1.height)
             fromRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, size2.width, size2.height)
            operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
             fraction:1.0];
[newImage unlockFocus];
```

It results in an image with the proper size (2 100x63 images result in a 100x126 image),but the two separate images are drawn way too small, so the resulting image is mostly blank :

[image: Screenshot]

Here are the original images :

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: What system are you targeting? You know that `compositeToPoint:` is deprecated in OSX10.6+?

Comment: Can you show your code that uses NSBitmapImageRep?

Comment: It's not deprecated, but you're right that I should not use it.

Comment: Check [Deprecated NSImage Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html) - you should be using DrawAtPoint:fromRect:operation :fraction: or DrawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:

Comment: *"If you are writing new code, or updating old code, you should avoid using this method. Instead, you should use the drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction: or drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction: method to draw the image. **Although the method itself is not deprecated**, the behavior it provides is not recommended for general use."*

Comment: what is your NSLog showing? ... and is there any reason you are using compositeAtPoint instead of drawAt...?

Comment: It does give pixel size... I'll quickly try drawAt... I was using the other method because I was just quickly testing out. 2 sec I'll update, thanks already!

Comment: No luck. The result is still an image that has the right size, yet the 2 images are drawn smaller (24 pixels width instead of 100, for example). This results in a mostly blank image.

Comment: Can you post your NSLog (update the question..)

Comment: I updated it, the input images are 100x63 in size.

Comment: @Korion: I'm pretty sure it's said that for longer than it's been in the deprecated section, so this would be a case where they moved it there without revising the text to remove that passage.

Comment: Oh okay! I just though, since XCode didn't give me a warning...

Comment: @Korion: You're right; it's not marked as deprecated in the header. Interesting. Either the docs are wrong or the header is wrong; either way, it might be worth a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Comment: I'll do that, thanks for the link Peter!!!

Comment: Correction : I'll do this when my family stops downloading so I can read a website in less than 10 minutes.

Comment: It's bug with ID = 12932691

Comment: @Korion, I am still looking at this, I've been doing some tests and getting very strange results with both drawAtPoint: and drawInRect: (similar to yours) - I'll post something in the next day or so... happy xmas!

Comment: Oh cool thank you!!! Happy christmas to you too!!!

Comment: Could you post the _actual_ images you are trying to manipulate? Add them to the question..

Comment: I figured it out, it works now by using `-drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you worked it out. I was getting similarly strange results when using your code. So I started to think I didn't really understand these methods.

I usually always use  `-drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction`, and although I wasn't 100% how the two rects affect the result, I have always got the result I needed.

Anyway I went away and made a little toy app to show the effect of modifying the rects interactively (using two images as per your issue).

[I've put it up on github](https://github.com/foundry/drawingtest), you might want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, using `-drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction` solved the problem!

Comment: Note that, to draw entire image, you can use a `fromRect` of `NSZeroRect` instead of `NSMakeRect(0, 0, size1.width, size1.height)`.